# How to find video file size or (time) length - on Amazon Drive?

Tags: amazon, amazon-cloud-drive

A client of mine shared with me a video file on *Amazon Drive*, viz.:

[image: Large video file on Amazon drive]

**Is there a way to find the file size (in Gigabytes) or file length (in minutes)?**